# how to create php regex

Tags: php, regex

I am trying to create a regex to replace a string.  Here is my pattern:

```
\{mailMerge: details_activity_number\\}
```

When  I do a search like this on a string like this:

```
hello {mailMerge: details_activity_number\}world
```

its fine.  But, if there's a line break like this:

```
hello \{
mailMerge: details_activity_number\} world
```

it breaks.  Here is my code in PHP:

```
 $pattern = '\{mailMerge: 'mailMerge: details_activity_number'\}';
 $content =  str_replace($pattern, $value, $content);
```

Can anyone help me with creating a pattern that would take into consideration possible line breaks/white spaces/etc to guarantee a match?

thanks

**EDIT**

```
private function  findAndReplace($content, $mergedArray){
    $test=$content;
    try{
        foreach($mergedArray as $ArrayKey => $ArrayValue){
            foreach ($ArrayValue  as $key => $value) {               
                $pattern = "\{\s*mailMerge:\s+". $key ."\s*\\\}";

                if($value){
                    $test =  preg_replace($pattern, $value, $test);
                }else{
                    $test =  preg_replace($pattern, "No Value Exists", $test);
                }
            }
        }
    }catch(Exception $e){
        throw $e;
    }
    return $test;
}
```

Comment: Sometimes you have `\{` and others you have `{`. Is the `\\` required?

Comment: Do you want a regular expression or a literal string? `str_replace` is for replacing literals. There are no regular expression pattern characters in `$pattern`.

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but a couple of really good resources for RegEx are regular-expressions.info and Regex Buddy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first version that you posted doesn't allow for any space between `{` and `m`. You need to do something like this:

```
\{\s*mailMerge:\s+details_activity_number\s*\\\}
```

The `\s*` means "match zero or more spaces (or other white space, like new lines) here." `\s+` means "match one or more spaces (or other white space, like new lines) here."

**NOTE:** Your code above uses `str_replace`, but you are trying to do a regex replace. You need to use `preg_replace` instead of `str_replace`, like in this code:

```
$content = "\{mailMerge: 'mailMerge: details_activity_number'\}";
$content =  preg_replace('/\{\s*mailMerge:\s+details_activity_number\s*\\\}/m', $value, $content);
```

**EDIT BASED ON COMMENTS:** Try this; it is working for me.

```
$value = "foo barrrrrr";

$content = "hello
{mailMerge: details_activity_number\} world";

$content =  preg_replace("/\\\\?\\{\s*mailMerge:\s+details_activity_number\s*\\\\?\\}/m", $value, $content);

echo $content; // produces "hello foo barrrrrr world"
```

Comment: Thank you for your response.  When I run this in a test site like: http://www.phpliveregex.com/ it's fine.  But when I run it in my php code it still fails.  do I have to escape the last two '\\' to make this work?

Comment: Try adding one more \ before the `}`. \\ just means an escaped \, so there's nothing escaping the `}`. You should also add `/m` (for "match across lines"), like this: `/\{\s*mailMerge:\s+details_activity_number\s*\\\}/m`

Comment: Thanks.  Still no luck.  Again, it works fine in a regex test site but when  I run my code it fails (the returned string is empty).  I added the full function, if that will help.  I really appreciate your help with this, as I'm against a deadline.

Comment: I clarified my answer somewhat; the code at bottom should address your problems. Mostly, it has to do with additional escaping.

Comment: now I get an error saying " NO MATCHES. CHECK FOR DELIMITER COLLISION.

Comment: Are you using myregextester.com to check that? Don't rely on an online tester for this; try it using actual PHP code. The code I posted works fine when it's actually run through PHP. It could be that your sample strings are improperly escaped above (and you are actually using something other than what appears on SO). I have tried to account for that, but all I can tell you is that the code I posted works.